# Any other way to download Windows App without going through the App Market?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am tinking about creating a Windows Mobile App but do not want to make it available on the Market.
The App will be for a select number of individuals (approx 40 ppl) and hence why I do not want it to be available to the public.
I have developed apps in Android before and you can just give the apk file to whom ever you like so that they can download it on their phone.

Can the same thing be done on Windows Apps?  Or if I have to put on the market, is there any restrictions you can set to who can download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options.

1. publish the application normally, and add a secondary level of security to control application access (username password)
2. Publish the application, but keep it [hidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj619160%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
3. Publish as an enterprise [application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206943%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), which doesn't sound like a good fit for your needs as described.

The second option is probably the best fit.

Comment: Option 2 is perfect, Thanks for that.